# POP3 Server: ERR Unsupported authentication type

Tags: email, authentication, telnet, pop3

I've installed **Axigen Mail Server** and enabled **SMTP** and **POP3** servers.

After that, I've created domain (*slava.local*) and an user (*slava*).

[image: Screenshot]

So now I can connect to the SMTP server (using `telnet`, open 127.0.0.1 25), and successfully send messages. Every message I send, arrives to the destination inbox of *slava* user. See the below screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

It is not the case when working with POP3 Server. I cannot pass the authentication, despite the fact that the *slava* user is created (and a password is set up as well).

**UPDATE**

Here is the error

```
+OK AXIGEN POP3 server on SLAVA-PC ready <12532.2077614192@SLAVA-PC>
USER slava
-ERR Unsupported authentication type
```

Any help/hint will be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post textual error messages as images. It makes your post hard to read, and inaccessible to search engines and people using screen readers. Please edit to include the error messages as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root of the problem and hence a **solution** as well.

In the `Axigen WebAdmin`, in the `POP3 server` configuration page, at Encryption and Authentication section,
I had to allow the following option: `On UNSECURED connections allow authentication with: normal login` ans `AUTH PLAIN` in order to enable authentication via `Telnet`, because `Telnet` in turn provides an unsecured connection.

Hopefully it will help someone.